# Colour in rendered object instance not correct and i have absolutely no idea in the whole damn world why

Tags: javascript, rendering

all i get is a little square with rgb(0,255,255) and i want the 'r' to be proportionate to the log (betterLog is a log function(base,answer)=exponent

everything

```
var ln = function(g){

    var n=g;
    n=abs(n);
    if(n>1){
        n=1/n;
    }
    var x=n-1;
    var output = x;
    var i;
    for(i = 2; i < 99; i++){
        if (i%2 === 0){
            output -= pow(x,i)/i;
        }
        if (i%2 === 1){
            output += pow(x,i)/i;
        }
    }
    return output;
};

var betterLog = function(a,b){
    var output = ln(b)/ln(a);
    return output;
};



var v=475;

var block = function(){
  this.render = function(){
    var stupidColor=(betterLog(2,v)*20);
    fill(stupidColor, 255, 255);
    rect(20,20,20,20);

  };
};

var newCrap = new block();


var draw = function() {
    newCrap.render(v);
};
```

its just a rgb(0,255,255) idk if its rendering correct5ly or not im new to js and its just not working as wanted no errors per se

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `Math`object to your functions

```js
var ln = function(g){
    var n=g;
    n=Math.abs(n);
    if(n>1){
        n=1/n;
    }
    var x=n-1;
    var output = x;
    var i;
    for(i = 2; i < 99; i++){
        if (i%2 === 0){
            output -= Math.pow(x,i)/i;
        }
        if (i%2 === 1){
            output += Math.pow(x,i)/i;
        }
    }
    return output;
};

var betterLog = function(a,b){
    var output = ln(b)/ln(a);
    return output;
};

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var fill = function(r,g,b,a){
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+','+a||1+')';
};
var rect = function(x,y,w,h){
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
};

var v=475;

var block = function(){
  this.render = function(v){
    var stupidColor=(betterLog(2,v)*20);
    fill(stupidColor, 255, 255);
    console.log({stupidColor});
    rect(20,20,20,20);
  };
};

var newCrap = new block();

var draw = function() {
    newCrap.render(v);
};

draw();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```